# Django page update no ajax or comet

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a small app for internal use between 3 people. the idea is to have a page where user can upload files and data ( more specifically images.) to the database and a second page where the information the user uploaded in the first page will be visible without having to manually refresh the page. I have read about comet and ajax and I think having a function check the Db every certain time is not what I'm looking for. Since there will be almost no updates in the DB. maybe every 3 to 4 months the user might update a new image.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ajax? It's basically what ajax is for.

Comment: I'm just started learning Django and python I have no experience with JS o AJAX .

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through at least one good tutorial on ajax & django, it's quite simple once you get started with it. But you can't really achieve this without AJAX.

Take a look at this;
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: i have  read a few tutorials on how to use ajax and Django to pull data from the DB, i think i get the general idea but I am still struggling  to apply any of those advises to my problem. on most tutorials i see that the ajax function has to be triggered by an html element like  form field  or input buttons. the problem i currently have is the page i need to update is a full screen image slider and i don't know what event could trigger the ajax listener function

Comment: @victorreyes1 yep, and that's where you'll come back to comet. Take a look at this perhaps; https://code.google.com/archive/p/django-orbited/